# Usage of environment variable of Travis CI in maven test

Tags: java, maven, github, travis-ci

I have one environmental variable 'password' which is added to settings of my travis repo. I need to add this to my travis(instead of my maven file in github) because it cannot be shared to public. Now, I need to use the password in my maven test execution.

without travis, I can pass variable to maven test file by executing

```
mvn -DargLine="-Dpassword=xxxxx" test
```

and in my java program, I can access the variable using

```
System.getProperty("password")
```

How can I achieve the same using travis if I need to trigger maven test from travis and pass the variable? I tried using System.getenv and System.getProperty. Both of them are not working.

Comment: Can't you set the environment variables of travis machine ? (The Java VM)

Comment: @SercanOzdemir can you please explain how?

Comment: We are using jenkins and, if we wanted to use an argument like this, we are setting java variables in system. As "-Dname=value", and you can use it as exporting below params:
JVM_OPTS="-Dmyname=myValue 
          -Dmyname2=mySecondValue"

Comment: i am not finding any way to make my password private. I can't add it in travis.yaml file as it is public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt your env variable with your puplic/private key in travis CI see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/.